# Renaming filename in SVN(sub version)

Tags: svn, renaming

The filename for a document includes a version number, is it possible to change the filename with new version after making changes in the document and commit the file in the same directory?

Client: TortoiseSVN 1.10.0
OS: Windows

Comment: Maybe `svn mv`?

Comment: TortoiseSVN has also a command called "Rename", available from the context menu

Comment: After renaming, will the file be treated as a new file?